# How to find time duration of covering a distance between two points

Tags: ios, core-location

I have drawn a route between the *source point* to the *destination point* and I have also found the distance between them by using `CoreLocation` Framework method "**distanceFromLocation**", but now I want to find time duration of covering a distance between these two points.

I have seen many guidelines but I have so far failed to get any solution. Can anyone please guide me to a solution or help answer how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is also my question we can not find time without velocity and distance. But i just want to know google provide any API which gives us time duration between these two points

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to build a route from source to destination point. You can do it either using Apple Maps or google maps. If you choose apple maps then you need to construct MKDirectionsRequest object (see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH8-SW5)). When you get a response you can check routes that Apple suggests you in MKDirectionsResponse object. Each MKRoute object has an [expectedTravelTime](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKRoute_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKRoute/expectedTravelTime) property